# Functions with the same product and with strictly positive sum of modulai

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Say we have two continuous complex-valued functions on $[0,1]$; call them $f,g$. Can we find another such functions $h,k$ such that $fg = hk$ and $|h(t)|+|k(t)|>0$ for all $t$?

The problem I see is with the case where the set $\{t: |h(t)|+|k(t)|=0\}$ contains points as connected components.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ and $g$ be such that $fg \equiv 0$.  Then $hk=0$ so $[0,1]$ is the union of disjoint closed sets $\{h=0\}$ and $\{k=0\}$. This contradicts the connectedness of $[0,1]$.