# Functions on the Cantor set with the same product and with $|h|+|k|>0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, cantor-set

Let me ask a variant of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806002/functions-with-the-same-product-and-with-strictly-positive-sum-of-modulai/3806010#3806010) but for the ternary Cantor set. We have two continuous complex-valued functions on the Cantor set $\Delta$; call them $f,g$. For $\varepsilon >0$, can we find another pair of such functions $h,k$ such that $fg = hk$, $\|f-h\|_\infty, \|g-k\|_\infty<\varepsilon$ (the supremum norm), and $|h(t)|+|k(t)|>0$ for all $t$?

That'd be the case if $\{f=0\} \cap \{g = 0\}$ were [clopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set).

Comment: What about $h=fg$ and $k=$ the constant function $1$.

Comment: @Crostul, oops forgot to include one requirement.